# I found a site that referenced my Sharepoint.stackexchange question without sources. Is it legal?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The title says it all. I googled my username to see what google had to say about me, and I fould [this site](http://sharepoint.findincity.net/), that referenced all my sharepoint related questions (i.e., I found [this](http://sharepoint.findincity.net/view/635399286724222582157434/how-to-organize-wiki-pages-in-sharepoint-2007) which is a carbon copy of [my SE question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92739/how-to-organize-wiki-pages-in-sharepoint-2007)).

Is this legal ? Isn't this some kind of site leeching question to generate views ? If that's the case, to who should I address my concerns ?